# Probleme when i run npm start,

Tags: node.js, angular

i have just started to learn angular 2, i tried to run npm start but it gives me this error in the navigator consol:

> Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
>   at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:698:29)
>   at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:35)
>   at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:47)
>   at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:335:33)
>   Error loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
>   Error loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap.js as "ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js

systemjs.config:

```
    /**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
* Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
  */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
        // paths serve as alias
        'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
        // our app is within the app folder
        app: 'app',
        // angular bundles
        '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
        '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
        '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
        '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
        '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
        '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
        // other libraries
        'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        'jquery': 'npm:jquery/',
        'lodash': 'npm:lodash/lodash.js',
        'moment': 'npm:moment/',
        'ng2-bootstrap': 'npm:ng2-bootstrap',
        'symbol-observable': 'npm:symbol-observable'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
        app: {
            main: './main.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
            main: './index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'moment': { main: 'moment.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'ng2-bootstrap': { main: 'ng2-bootstrap.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'symbol-observable': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    }
     });
      })(this);
```

app.module.ts:

```
import './rxjs-operators';
//Modules
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
//bootstrap components
import { PaginationModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { DatepickerModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { Ng2BootstrapModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { ModalModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { ProgressbarModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { TimepickerModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

 //components && directives && routes && pipes
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { DateFormatPipe } from './shared/pipes/date-format.pipe';
import { HighlightDirective } from './shared/directives/highlight.directive';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { MobileHideDirective } from './shared/directives/mobile-hide.directive';
import { ScheduleEditComponent } from './schedules/schedule-edit.component';
import { ScheduleListComponent } from './schedules/schedule-list.component';
import { UserCardComponent } from './users/user-card.component';
import { UserListComponent } from './users/user-list.component';
import { routing } from './app.routes';

///services
import { DataService } from './shared/services/data.service';
import { ConfigService } from './shared/utils/config.service';
import { ItemsService } from './shared/utils/items.service';
import { MappingService } from './shared/utils/mapping.service';
import { NotificationService } from './shared/utils/notification.service';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
    DatepickerModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    Ng2BootstrapModule,
    ModalModule,
    ProgressbarModule,
    PaginationModule,
    routing,
    TimepickerModule
],
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DateFormatPipe,
    HighlightDirective,
    HomeComponent,
    MobileHideDirective,
    ScheduleEditComponent,
    ScheduleListComponent,
    UserCardComponent,
    UserListComponent
],
providers: [
    ConfigService,
    DataService,
    ItemsService,
    MappingService,
    NotificationService
  ],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
  export class AppModule { }
```

package.json:

```
{
"version": "1.0.0",
"name": "scheduler",
"author": "Chris Sakellarios",
"license": "MIT",
"repository": "https://github.com/chsakell/angular2-features",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0",
"@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6",

"jquery": "^3.0.0",
"lodash": "^4.13.1",
"moment": "^2.13.0",
"ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.5",
"ng2-slim-loading-bar": "1.5.1",

"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"systemjs": "0.19.27",
"zone.js": "^0.6.23",
"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20"
 },
"devDependencies": {
"concurrently": "^2.0.0",
"del": "^2.2.0",
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-tslint": "^5.0.0",
"jquery": "^3.0.0",
"lite-server": "^2.2.0",
"typescript": "2.0.2",
"typings": "^1.3.2",
"tslint": "^3.10.2"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite --baseDir ./app --port 8000\" ",
"lite": "lite-server",
"postinstall": "typings install",
"tsc": "tsc",
"tsc:w": "tsc -w",
"typings": "typings"
}
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="/">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Scheduler</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="bower_components/alertify.js/themes/alertify.core.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="bower_components/alertify.js/themes/alertify.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/styles.css" />

<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/alertify.js/lib/alertify.min.js"></script>

<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
 <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
 </head>
<body>
<scheduler>
    <div class="loader"></div>    
</scheduler>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you just have the mapping incorrect in your system.js try mapping `moments` and `ng2-bootstrap` like this..

```
'moment': 'node_modules/moment/moment.js',
'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js',
```

**EDIT**

I would re-run `npm install ng2-bootstrap --save`
make sure you have the correct cdn in you index.html here

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Remove the second ng2-bootstrap from ALL your import statements in your app module.
change `ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap` to just `ng2-bootstrap`. Also you do not have to make an import statement for all the modules that you are importing. try this instead

```
import { Ng2BootstrapModule, DatepickerModule, PaginationModule, etc.... } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
```

Comment: Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3002/ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap.js
     at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange]

Comment: have you gone into your `node_modules` folder and ensured you actually have `ng-bootstrap` installed?